# Calculating jpeg size from dimensions and bit depth

Tags: jpeg, libjpeg, jpeg2000

I have jpeg file with following details
[ExampleJPEG File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjgUZ.png)

The file size is 1342 bytes as shown above and also confirmed by Hex Editor.

I was thinking i could also calculate the file size by using its dimensions and bit depth.
i.e Total Bytes = ( Width X Height X bitDepth ) / 8

(28 X 28 X 24) / 8  = 2352 bytes

Why is this difference?  The calculation formula says 2352 bytes whereas actual size is 1342 bytes. What am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

When expanded out (decoded) and held as bytes in memory (RAM), the image will indeed occupy 2,352 bytes. But [JPEGs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) are compressed to save space on disk, camera SD cards and when being Emailed and transmitted, so they are smaller and take less space/bandwidth.

---

If you want to see the pixel intensities in their expanded out RGB format, you can use a tool such as **ImageMagick** in the Terminal/command-line. Let's make a red image 28x28 - I'll make it in PNG format for now:

```
magick -size 28x28 xc:red PNG24:image.png
```

[image]

Now, if you want to view the pixels, you can either convert the image to a text dump with **ImageMagick** like this:

```
magick image.png -depth 8 -colorspace rgb txt:
```

**Sample Output**

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 28,28,65535,rgb
0,0: (255,0,0)  #FF0000  rgb(255,0,0)
1,0: (255,0,0)  #FF0000  rgb(255,0,0)
2,0: (255,0,0)  #FF0000  rgb(255,0,0)
3,0: (255,0,0)  #FF0000  rgb(255,0,0)
...
...
24,27: (255,0,0)  #FF0000  rgb(255,0,0)
25,27: (255,0,0)  #FF0000  rgb(255,0,0)
26,27: (255,0,0)  #FF0000  rgb(255,0,0)
27,27: (255,0,0)  #FF0000  rgb(255,0,0)
```

---

Or, if you want to view them in a more raw form of hex:

```
convert image.png -depth 8 rgb:image.raw
```

and view `image.raw` in a hex editor, or use Linux built-in tools:

```
convert image.png -depth 8 rgb: | xxd -g 3 -c12 | more
00000000: ff0000 ff0000 ff0000 ff0000  ............
0000000c: ff0000 ff0000 ff0000 ff0000  ............
00000018: ff0000 ff0000 ff0000 ff0000  ............
```

---

Note that if you check the size of the raw, uncompressed (decoded) image, you will see it happily matches your calculation of 2,352 bytes:

```
ls -l image.raw
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  2352 27 Aug 09:56 image.raw
```

---

Note that I used PNG rather than JPEG above because JPEG is lossy and you don't get back what you save, you get something that looks similar but takes less space - like I said above.

Here is an example. I'll draw a red and a green line on a black background and save as a PNG and count the colours:

```
magick -size 100x100 xc:black +antialias -fill red -draw "line 5,5 95" -fill lime -draw "line 95,5 5,95" image.png
```

[image]

Now count the colours:

```
magick -format %k image.png info:
3
```

Now do exactly he same thing as a lossy JPEG:

```
magick -size 100x100 xc:black +antialias -fill red -draw "line 5,5 95,95" image.jpg
```

And count the colours in the JPEG and there are 148 now:

```
magick -format %k image.jpg info:
148
```

**Keywords**: Image Processing, ImageMagick, JPEG, lossy, PNG lossless, prime.

Comment: Ok. So you mean the calculation I did is for decoded image. Is there any way I can actually see this specific image after decoding?

Comment: Just open it in Photoshop, GIMP, feh or Windows Picture Viewer and those programs will decode and display the JPEG.

Comment: Perfect. I think my intention was to get hold of the view after decoding like i can see the jpeg file in HEX editor before its decoded. Is there any trick by which i could see the decoded version of the same file via HEX editor?

Comment: I have updated my answer - please take another look.